# Transparent dialog in android

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog

I am using some checkboxes and it is displayed on a dialogbox(dynamically).The next thing i need to make that dialog box  transparent.I tried many methods,but failed(wasted the entire day behind this).Can anyone please give me a solution

NB:Currently i am getting a white colour inside the dialog box(Not transparent)
Below is the code.....
Transparent_alert.java

```
public class Transparent_alert extends Activity{
    String tag="Transparent_alert class";
    static final String KEY_USERID = "userid";
    String errormsg = "", user_id;
    SessionManager session;
    int k=0;
    Intrested_in_adapter m_adapter;
    private Builder mDialog;
    private Dialog alertDialog;
    List<Requestencapsulation> offferList;
    List<Offeringencapsulation> offerlist;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        user_id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);
        setContentView(R.layout.requests);
        new Serviceclass1().execute();

}
class Serviceclass1 extends
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                UserFunctions usf = new UserFunctions();
                Log.e(tag,"user_id"+user_id);
                JSONObject json2 = usf.intrestlist(user_id);


                JSONArray contacts = json2
                        .getJSONArray("interested_list");


                for (int j = 0; j < contacts.length(); j++) {
                    Log.e(tag, "intrestedin  forloop");

                    JSONObject c = contacts
                            .getJSONObject(j);
                    Requestencapsulation bean = new Requestencapsulation();
                    bean.setIntrest_id(c
                            .getString("interested_id"));
                    bean.setIntrest_name(c
                            .getString("interested_name"));

                    bean.setKey_status(c
                            .getString("status"));

                    if (c.getString("interested_info")
                            .equals("null"))

                    {
                        bean.setInterested_info("");

                    } else {
                        bean.setInterested_info(c
                                .getString("interested_info"));

                    }
                    offferList.add(bean);

                }
                k=offferList.size();                                                                        
            }
                catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            new Serviceclass2().execute();
        }
}

class Serviceclass2 extends
AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            UserFunctions usf1 = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json3= usf1.offerlistlist(user_id);
            JSONArray contacts1 = json3.getJSONArray("offer_list");


            for (int i = 0; i < contacts1.length(); i++) {
                Log.e(tag,"INSIDE OFFERING LOOP");
                JSONObject d= contacts1.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.e(tag,"CREATED JSON OBJECT");
                Requestencapsulation bean=new Requestencapsulation();
                Log.e(tag,"OBJECT CREATED FOR OFFERINGENCAPSULATION");

                bean.setIntrest_id(d
                        .getString("offer_id"));
                Log.e(tag,
                        "offerid is::"
                                + d.getString("offer_id"));

                bean.setIntrest_name(d
                        .getString("offer_name"));
                Log.e(tag,
                        "offer name is::"
                                + d.getString("offer_name"));
                bean.setKey_status(d.getString("status"));
                Log.e(tag,
                        "status is"
                                + d.getString("status"));
//              if (d.getString("offer_info").equals(
//                      "null")) {
//                  bean.setInterested_info(d
//                          .getString("interested_info"));
//              } else {
//                  bean.setInterested_info(d
//                          .getString("interested_info"));
//
//              }
                offferList.add(bean);
                Log.e(tag,"process for bean1 completed");

                ;
                }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        new Serviceclass2().execute();
        Context c = getParent();
        m_adapter = new Intrested_in_adapter(
                Transparent_alert.this,
                R.layout.intrestedin, offferList);

        mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);

        mDialog.setTitle("Intrested In");

        mDialog.setAdapter(m_adapter,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(
                            DialogInterface dialog,
                            int item) {

                    }
                });

        alertDialog = mDialog.create();
         alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

intrestedin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"


    >
     <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"

         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Intrested_in_adapter.java

```
public class Intrested_in_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Requestencapsulation>{
    CheckBox checkbox;
    CheckBox checkbox1;
    private  List<Requestencapsulation> alist;
    private List<Offeringencapsulation> alist1;
    public Intrested_in_adapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public Intrested_in_adapter(Context context, int resource, List<Requestencapsulation> items) {

        super(context, resource,items);
        this.alist=items;

        Log.e("Inside Constructor","list size is:"+alist.size());
    }
    @Override
    public Requestencapsulation getItem(int position) {
         return alist.get(position);

    }
    public long getId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//      ViewHolder mHolder;
        Requestencapsulation p = getItem(position);


        if (convertView == null) {
            Log.e("inside convertview","inside convertview");
              convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.intrestedin, parent, false);

           }        
        if (p != null) {
//          mHolder = new ViewHolder();
             checkbox=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

             if(alist.get(position).getKey_status().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
             {
            checkbox.setSelected(true);
            }else{
                checkbox.setSelected(false);
            }
             checkbox.setText(alist.get(position).getIntrest_name());

        }



        return convertView;

    }
}
```

maifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gatekeeper.dropswitch"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.gate.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gate.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/gate_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Redirectclass"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" 
            android:name="com.example.gate.Userpage"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity

            android:name="com.example.gate.Guardpage"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Transparent_alert"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Registerpage"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.ProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Selectbuttonfromrequestclass"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Actionclass"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.TabGroup1Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Tabgroup2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Tabgroup3"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.gate.MainActivity" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Homenext"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Family"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.FamilyMain"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Familyedit"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.GuestMain"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Guest"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Guestedit"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Services"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Addprovider"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Addservices"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Offering"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Interest"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Accesspreferences"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.ActionActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Messageclass"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Report"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Requestclass"

            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Notify"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Rsidenceinfo"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Latestservice"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Guardactiongroup"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Guardprofilegroup"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Guardinfogroup"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Otherresidence"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Directoryguardedit"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Guardaction"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.skype.raider.Main"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="0" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="tel" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Guardinfo"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Guardprofile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.video"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Guard_message_class"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Guard_report_class"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Guard_notify_class"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.Guard_request_class"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name="com.example.gate.guard_addnew_residence"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.gate.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.example.gate" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.example.gate.GcmIntentService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am not getting any clue to do this .Please anybody help.Any help will be highly appreciated....

Comment: show your manifest file. you might be using some theme.

Comment: Manifest  is added above

Comment: please post your activity xml

Comment: @bhavesh exceeding the limit while posting my activity xml

Comment: @VishnuM there is no need of manifest file and other xtra code over here. or just give your mail layout color transparent color and as well as to your listivew. define background.

Comment: ok Bhavesh my mail id is vishnumohan08@yahoo.in

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna make your alertdialog transparent i don't know if it's possible but customizing an alertdialog like the code as displayed below is more suitable for this you just need to create an xml file which makes a design exactly similar to your current alert box and can make it as transparent.

```
    dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_profile_report);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        dialog.show();
Button mainListView = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listview); // you can declare elements like this and can make onclick methods for these elements
```

Comment: @VishnuM it doesn't matter just vomit that line.

Comment: @Karthika...it wont works for me now....after some more steps i need your code...I will defenitely inform you after sometime ....thanku

Comment: @VishnuM this is a working code for me can you please post the new code?

Comment: Karthika i edited code section in my qustion and changed to what i am doing now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74324/discussion-between-karthika-pb-and-vishnu-m).

Answer (score 0):

try making your dialog transparent, like this

intrestedin.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

please put below code in style

```
 <style name="CustomAlert" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

***Code:***

```
Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(baseApplication.getCurrentActivity(),
                        R.style.CustomAlert);
                mDialog.setCancelable(true);
                mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.inflate_toast);

//you can set height width of dialog as well as position
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                Window window = mDialog.getWindow();

            lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            window.setAttributes(lp);

mDialog.show();
```

**In your activity xml:**

**set background as transparent color to listview, listview's divider,and  inflated layout of listview.**

Comment: but i am using an adapter.Now i posted my adapter class aso on the top...can you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Replace</strike>

```
alertDialog = mDialog.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

with

```
alertDialog = mDialog.create();
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
alertDialog.show();
```

**Issue:**
Your adapter is inflating row layout to display in ListView. and as you can see, it is going to reference with Parent container while inflating using LayoutInflater.
It is creating problem while making everything transparent.

**Option 1 :**
  You should consider using `Dialog` instead of `AlertDialog` and should set your desired layout by using `setContentView`

**Option 2 :**
You will have some drawback because of old api but it will work in new apis

replace

```
mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
```

with

```
mDialog = (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) < 11)? new AlertDialog.Builder(c) :new AlertDialog.Builder(c, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
```

Comment: i already tested it...but no change in background(not transparent)